# Return data from mysql with date later than now

Tags: mysql, date

Here's table I've got:

```
projects(p_id,p_name,p_deadline)
```

`p_deadline`  is defined in MySQL as DATE.

How to write a query that returns only projects with `p_deadline` date that is newer than `NOW()`? I don't want to display projects that passed deadline date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  ... whatever ...
FROM
  ... whatever ...
WHERE
  ... whatever ...
  AND projects.p_deadline>NOW();
```

Comment: It's that simple? I was looking at datetime functions and I was kind of confused that's why I wanted to know exactly how to write the code. Thank you very much.

Comment: It is. I didn't fill out the rest of the query, as I suspect you want some joins or other stuff.

Comment: But how do I get data even from day equal to the NOW();? I tried >= but it doesn't seem to work, I guess because NOW(); returns even the time.

Comment: ... `AND projects.p_deadline>=DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL HOUR(CURRENT_TIME()) HOUR),INTERVAL MINUTE(CURRENT_TIME()) MINUTE),INTERVAL SECOND(CURRENT_TIME()) SECOND)`

Comment: @jesteuvidim - Re: *I tried >= but it doesn't seem to work* See my response about using curDate(). (It was too long for a comment)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE p_dealine > NOW()
```

Answer (score 0):

(Just to clarify one point ..)

> But how do I get data even from day equal to the NOW();? I tried >=
>   but it doesn't seem to work, I guess because NOW(); returns even the
>   time

Correct. `DATE` values have a time of midnight. Since now() returns both a date *and* time the two values will rarely match. Only at midnight. So the actual comparison translates to something like this:

```
/* notice the dates match, but the current time is later */
WHERE '2012-02-17 00:00:00' >= '2012-02-17 13:35:48'
```

Instead you should use [`curDate()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate). It returns a date (only).

```
WHERE p_deadline >= CURDATE();
```